# Sending an array to PHP function from javascript and reading its values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a onclick and post function in jQuery where I pass two variables to my PHP function.

The functions look like following:

```
$(".pop-save-us").click(function(){
    console.log(checkbox_events);
    console.log(user_id);
  // alert("Button save pressed");
    $.post('/user/AddRemoveBrandUsers', { brands: JSON.stringify(checkbox_events),userId:user_id} , function(data) {
        if(checkbox_events.length==0)
        {
            alert("No changes were made.")
        }
        else {
            if (data == "ok") {
             alert("ok");
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The first value is an array in following format:

console.log(checkbox_events) gives a following output:

```
[2: "checked", 4: "checked", 5: "checked"]
```

I do `JSON.stringify(checkbox_events) to turn my array into JSON format and pass it to my PHP function like following:

```
 public function AddRemoveBrandUsersAction()
    {
        $brands = $this->getRequest()->getPost("brands");
        $userId = $this->getRequest()->getPost("userId");
        for($i=0;$i<count($brands);$i++)
        {
         // how can I now access each value of the brands array 
         // I need both key and value... How do I access them ??
        }
        die("ok");
    }
```

Comment: So, you wanna use a `foreach($array as $key => $value)` ?

Comment: Okay can you reply in a form of answer so that I can accept ur answer.... And how do I get the "checked" value inside the loop ??

Comment: What do you mean by "checked" value? If you are referring to a checkbox or radio, then the value / input is only sent if they are checked?

Comment: You dont check if its checked on PHP side, you only pass the checked value to server side.

Comment: yes thats what i ment danny... u can see that I have the "checked" stored in the array and then passed to PHP function. Question is, how can I access the: [2: "checked" << this value  $key => $value is going to be =2 , but how to access the "checked" as well ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the code follows:

```
 if(!empty($brands) && sizeof($brands) > 0){
     foreach($brands as $key => $value){
         ...
     }
 }
```

Comment: Okay the $key is going to be the = 2 value... But how do i get the string value which is "checked" inside the loop? :)

Comment: $value is 'checked' text

Comment: and $key is =2 ? :)

Comment: exactly $key is 2 and $value is 'checked'

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
json_decode(%your_string_with_json%)
```

function to get the internal php representation of your json string. Thus, you will be able to manipulate it (get data, set data). It's very useful to use debugger also.

```
$a = json_decode('{"foo": 123, "bar": null, "baz": "qwerty", "arr": ["hello", "world"]}', true);
```

Will give you and array, which you can easily use within your code:

```
array (
  'foo' => 123,
  'bar' => NULL,
  'baz' => 'qwerty',
  'arr' => 
  array (
    0 => 'hello',
    1 => 'world',
  ),
)
```

For example:

```
$b = $a['foo'] // b = 123
$b = $a['arr'][0] // b = hello
```

Then, you should watch the value you have received from the request, and depending on it, use if ... else ... and etc.